# how to get specific value in python dictionary?

Tags: python, django

I call an api via python and return this code as response:

```
        {
          "cast": [
            {
              "character": "Power",
              "name": "George"
            },
            {
              "character": "Max",
              "job": "Sound",
              "name": "Jash"
            },
            {
              "character": "Miranda North",
              "job": "Writer",
              "name": "Rebecca"
            }
          ]
        }
```

I am trying to get the value of Rebecca because i need to get the Writer.
So i wrote:

```
for person in cast # cast is the variable keeps whole code above NOT inside the dict:
    if person["job"] == "Writer":
        writer = person["name"]
```

but it gives me:

```
KeyError at search/15
u'job'
```

how can i get the value?

FULL CODE:

```
writer = ""
for person in api['cast']:
    if person.get('job') == 'Writer':
        writer = person.get('name')
return render(request, 'home.html', {
    'writer': writer
})
```

home.html:

```
<p>{{writer}}</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because not all elements in the list have the `job` key.

Change to:

```
for person in cast #whole code above:
    if person.get('job') == 'Writer':
        writer = person.get('name')
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have assign writer = '' before the forloop and when the template loads, in the point i print the writer, it shows me nothing.

Comment: Since you gave it a default value of an empty string (`''`) and a `writer` is not found then an empty string will be rendered in the template. If you don't want that put `{% if writer %}<p>{{writer}}</p>{% endif %}` in your template.\

Comment: I was getting an api callback without job included..you were correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One liner to find one writer.

```
writer = next((person for person in api['cast'] if person.get('job') == 'Writer'), None)
```

One liner to find all writers.

```
writers = [person for person in api['cast'] if person.get('job') == 'Writer']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Syntax for dictionary get() method:

dict.get(key, default=None)

Parameters
    key: This is the Key to be searched in the dictionary.
    default: This is the Value to be returned in case key does not exist.
```

You need to specify the default value for `get` in case the `key` doesn't exist.

```
>>> for person in api['cast']:
...   if person.get('job', '') == 'Writer':
...     writer = person.get('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

person.get(u"job") == "Writer"

Answer (score 0):

`for person in cast["cast"]:
 # cast is the variable keeps whole code above NOT inside the dict
        if person["job"] == "Writer":
            writer = person["name"]`

try this

cast["cast"] == Value of Key "cast" , which in turn is list of Dicts 
and for looping through each Dictionary as person